# Error on starting the WildFly server (address already in use)

Tags: server, jboss, wildfly, solaris

I have a problem starting a wildfly app-server (wildfly-21.0.1) on a Solaris server (computer). I have read a lot of similar posts, but my problem seems to be different.
First, I make an SSH-tunnel in PuTTY:
[image: Session]

[image: Tunnels]
My home machine is Windows, I connect to a remote Solaris server. I write the address of the server in a "Host name" field.
After this I create an SSH tunnel on a port of the server (I tried different and rare ones), so I put the port of the server I am connecting to in "Source port" field and the port of my personal machine (localhost:port_number) in the "Destination".
I have configured standalone.xml by changing on

```
<interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
```

and

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:14384}"/>
```

I have configured PATH and JAVA_HOME on the server.
I start the server by

```
bash wildfly-21.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh
```

command.
After this I get the following error:

```
 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:14384
```

It happens with any ports I tried, and I am sure that they aren't in use.
How can I fix this? Are there any known bugs in Wildfly that can cause this? Is it somehow connected with tunneling?

Comment: *It happens with any ports I tried, and I am sure that they aren't in use.*  And just how are you sure they aren't in use?  Did you actually run something like `netstat -an -f inet -P tcp` and see if anything is actually using that port?  You can't be "sure" about something like this if you haven't actually checked.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Of course, I checked this.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Because your Putty configuration image shows that you're forwarding remote port 14384 to your local port 14384.  ***Which means the `sshd` process on the remote host is listening on port 14384 which is why JBoss is returning the `Address already in use /0.0.0.0:14384` error.***  From the data in your question, I have to say the odds of you having actually checked immediately before trying to start JBoss that port 14384 isn't in use is pretty low.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Yes, you're right! I checked this before tunneling - that's why I didn't see it was in use. How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion with @AndrewHenle made me think of ports usage in a tunneling procedure so I changed "Remote" parameter in "Tunnels" section on "Local" (since the destination is localhost). All the other parameters and values were left the same. Now everything works correctly, and WildFly doesn't recognise 14384 as a taken port.